# Connecting one app Service to another using private link

Tags: azure, microservices, azure-appservice, azure-vpn, azure-private-link

I am trying to connect my apps together privately.
Here is the setup:

1. Webapp FrontEnd (Node 18) :
2. Webapp Backend (.NET7)
3. webApp CosmosDb (Azure Cosmos DB account)

Network Configuration:

1. the frontend and backend are in the same app service plan Linux Basic: B2.
2. frontEnd is public  exposed
3. backend is public blocked but has private endpoint
4. frontEnd is trying to call backend using the https://backend-dev.azurewebsites.net
5. All the subnets have the Micrsoft.Web service added. The frontend subnet has the webfarms delegation
6. backend has the CORS with "*" added.
7. The DNS are setup for all private links

Status:

- From the Frontend SCM I can do a curl to this backend url. I get proper response
- from browser I am getting 403

  - Request has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
  - tried with "https://backend-dev.privatelink.azurewebsites.net" in frontnend code but did not work

Can someone help me out please. I tried the setups in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65069698/azure-app-service-to-app-service-communication-via-private-link) as well. No luck

here is the resource graph
[image]

nslookup from frontend ssh

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing I would check - are the private DNS zones linked to the vNet? This has cost me more pain than anything else in setups like this. Does the frontend resolve backend-dev.azurewebsites.net to the expected private IP?

Comment: yes the nslookup from the frontend ssh  is resolving to the vnet ip address. uploading the nslookup